# TrackedSymbols affected by CurrentValue. Another problem with SetDelayed(:=)+OwnVales in Initialization

Tags: graphics, dynamic, scoping

It is MWE, only a `Disk[]` that should print `"Click"` when clicked.

Also `"date... updating"` should be printed on the first evaluation and on each update of variable `enabled`. (which is **constant** in this MWE)

In the `Column` there is another `Dynamic` object which shows current `MousePosition`. And this element is responsible for printing (flooding) `"date... updating"` even though `enabled` is not changing.

```
DynamicModule[{enabled = True, pos},
 Column[{
        Dynamic[Print[DateString[] <> " updating"];
                EventHandler[Graphics@Disk[], {"MouseClicked" :> Print["Click"]}],
                TrackedSymbols :> {enabled}]
        ,
        Dynamic[pos]
        }]
 , Initialization :> (pos := MousePosition["Graphics"])]
```

[image]

I think I don't understand this and IMO it is not expected or desired behaviour.

When one put another `Print` next to `Graphics` you will see that it is in face whole `Graphics` updating.

**So the question is**:

If it's not a bug (I missed something) then how to recreate this MWE so it behaves correctly.

---

I think it may be (but not necessarily) related to [Why does a heavy background slow LocatorPane from updating, even if only the locators are Dynamic?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43152/5478)

p.s. `Dynamic[Refresh[..., TrackedSymbols:>{enabled}]]` behaves the same way.

---

**Edit** so at the end it seems to be more related to [Button evaluation inside DynamicModule](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29129/button-evaluation-inside-dynamicmodule)

Comment: Ah I finally understand, somehow I read constant as constantly, which is quite different :P.

Comment: Hm see update, maybe it has something to do with `DynamicModuleValues`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(This is more of an extended comment until a better understanding evolves.)

Finally I've found the relevant [MathGroup thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/PR6f89JG2J4/uSm0Us_63zYJ) from old - apparently the behaviour is as old as the dynamic interactivity in *Mathematica*. At that time, [Norbert Pozar](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/PR6f89JG2J4/-ni85zFc9kwJ) introduced a really simple example to demonstrate the strange internals of `DynamicModule` when a symbol in an `Initialization` assignment sets `OwnValues` instead of `DownValues` with `SetDelayed` (`Set` is fine). Be aware, **this will probably crash your kernel!**

```
DynamicModule[{x}, 1, Initialization :> (x := Print["Should never see this."])]
```

However, changing the assignment to `something[]:=...` works as expected. Clearly, `DynamicModule` evaluates the symbol `x` internally, even if it is never used; and if the symbol has side effects, that can be catastrophic.

**Bottom line: always use `DownValues` instead of `Onwvalues`** when doing assignments inside `Initialization` code in `DynamicModule`. Like that:

```
DynamicModule[{x}, 1, Initialization :> (x[]:= Print["Should never see this."])]
```

---

Spelunking in the definition of `DynamicModule`, I've found that the problem is even more deeply embedded: it must be in `DynamicModuleBox`. The following example still crashes a fresh kernel:

```
CellPrint@Cell@BoxData@DynamicModuleBox[{x}, 1, 
    Initialization :> (x := Print["Should never see this!"])]
```

Comment: Great thread! Thanks.

Comment: @Kuba Unfortunately, no one from WRI replied to that MG thread so the only option we have is to explore the definition of `DynamicModule`.

Comment: I've pined JohnFultz in chat yesterday. I would love to see an explanation. p.s. added example for clarity, hope you don't mind.

Comment: p.s. `OwnValues` are ok with `Set`, worth adding in *bottom line* that it is in context of `SetDelayed`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this does what you want?

```
DynamicModule[
 {enabled = True, pos},
 Column[
  {
   Dynamic[
    Print[DateString[] <> " updating"];
    EventHandler[
     Graphics@Disk[], {"MouseClicked" :> Print["Click"]}
     ]
    ]
   ,
   Dynamic[pos[]]
   }
  ]
 ,
 Initialization :> (pos[] := MousePosition["Graphics"])
 ]
```

Really... trial and error.

Comment: That seems hopeful, doesn't it? I'm not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: Just talking :P it's something but it will not help me, the main issue is still there. Now testking your answer...

Comment: So the answer is: never ever use `SetDelayed` for `OwnValues` purposes of `DynamicModule` variables. Why? Everything is crazy then.