# possible memory problem with WatershedComponents

Tags: warning-messages, memory

This could be regarded as a follow-up question to a previous post of mine ([link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148317/using-highlightimage-on-a-large-image-causes-a-display-error)).

When I use the WatershedComponents function on a large image (about 6000 x 10000 pixels) Mathematica comes up with an error message:

[image]

This error occurs in Mathematica versions 10.4, 11.0, and 11.1 running on a 64bit Win 8.1pro machine with 32GB RAM.

**EDIT**

Here is a sample image and some code to reproduce the above mentioned behaviour

```
img = Import["http://i.imgur.com/SY5OVkY.jpg"];



(*3000 x 3000 pixels*)
WatershedComponents[ImagePad[img, 1000, "Reflected"]]; (*this works*)

(*9000 x 9000 pixels*)
WatershedComponents[ImagePad[img, 4000, "Reflected"]]; (*this works*)

(*13000 x 13000 pixels*)
WatershedComponents[ImagePad[img, 6000, "Reflected"]]; (*this results in the error message:*)
```

> LinkRead::linkep: An unexpected end of packet was received.
>      ImageData::imginv: Expecting an image or graphics instead of $Aborted.

Comment: Please provide a link to the image.

Comment: @Alexey: I have added an example image and some code.

Comment: This *may* indicate a bug in the component ITK.exe which the kernel uses under the hood. I can't test myself since I have no access to a computer with 32 GB of RAM. I suggest you contacting the tech support.

Comment: I have already contacted tech support and I am waiting for an answer ;).